# UICollectionViewLayout tutorials

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

Beginner here,

I am trying to track down some good tutorials on UICollectionViewLayout subclasses but i can't seem to find any. Most tutorials out there seem to be about collectionView basics and the stock UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Has anyone come across any helpful tutorials for a implementing a custom UICollectionViewLayout?

thanks!

**UPDATE**

this one was super helpful for me

http://www.skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the sample code that accompanies the WWDC 2012 videos and look the example code for videos 205 and 219. Look at the layout that arranges views in a circle, for instance.